# Const correctness of C++ copy constructor is ignored?

Tags: c++, constants, copy-constructor

Take this example code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Address
{
  public:
    mutable unsigned key;

    Address() : key(0) {};
    Address(int a) : key(a) {};

    // const Address but compiler lets us modify it anyway!
    Address(const Address &n) : key(++n.key) {};
    void showKey() { cout << "key is " << key << endl;}
    void modifyKey(int k) { key = k;}
};

int main()
{
  cout << "Address a " << endl;
  Address a;
  a.showKey();

  cout << "Address b " << endl;
  Address b(a);
  b.showKey();

  if (b.key == a .key)
    cerr << "Wow the compiler doesn't care about const correctness" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The copy constructor of the `Address` class says that `n` if a reference to a constant `Address` object. Therefore I expect modifications to the object referenced by `n` to be disallowed. It seems that directly manipulating `n`'s fields is allowed by the compiler. However I did notice if I add a non `const` method to Address and call it on `n` inside the copy constructor (e.g. `n.myNonConstMethod()`) the compiler will complain.

I am surprised that this code compiles (I've tried g++ and clang++ and they compile with out errors or warnings). Have I misunderstood the use of `const` (it wouldn't be the first time!) or are these compiler bugs?

Comment: The constructor **is** const correct, the compiler is ensuring that, you just told the compiler that `key` is `mutable`, so it can be changed on a constant object.

Comment: less aggressive comment... With `mutable` you explicitly specified that the key field can be modified even if the object is const.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : Oops that was stupid. I copied chunks of the class code from another project so I could play with a few bits of it and completely missed that. Face palm!

Answer (score 3):

[Pulled from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2h0ktk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> This keyword [`mutable`] can only be applied to non-static and non-const data members of a class. If a data member is declared mutable, then it is legal to assign a value to this data member from a const member function.